# If p is an odd prme and (t,p) = 1, then $t^2$ is not a primitive root $\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

If p is an odd prime and (t,p) = 1, then $t^2$ is not a primitive root $\pmod p$.

proof:  If g is a primitive root $\pmod p$ and if t is an integer such that (t,p) = 1, then there exist an integer k such that $0 \le k \le \varphi(p) -1$ and $t \equiv g^k\pmod p$.

Then suppose $t^2$ is a primitive root, then $g = t^2$. S.

Maybe if p is an odd prime, then g is a primitive root $\pmod p$, then $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod p$?
I don't know if this helps.

I don't really understand. Can someone please help me start? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A start:** We have by Fermat's Theorem that $t^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

It follows that $(t^2)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: does t have order (p-1) because  k =< φ(p) -1 ? And (t2)^[(p−1)/2]≡1(modp). follows from  p is an odd prime, then g is a primitive root (modp), then g^[(p-1)/2] == -1(modp)?

Comment: The fact that $p$ is odd implies that $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is an integer. From $(t^2)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod p$ we conclude that $t^2$ has order $\le \frac{p-1}{2}\lt p-1$, so cannot be a primitive root. (Recall that the primitive roots, essentially by definition, are the elements of order $p-1$.)

Comment: What you write about $g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1$ is correct, and can be used in the proof, but what I suggest is more basic, and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the group homomorphism $q\colon (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times\to (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$, $x\mapsto x^2$. Since $-1\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $q(-1)=g(1)$, it has nontrivial kernel, i.e. its image is a *proper* subgroup, hence cannot contain any generator of the group.